# How to select the first child by class that goes after similar element without class?

Tags: css

How can I select the first element with class "red" (First) in this construction?

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <p>Zero</p>
    <p class="red">First</p>
    <p class="red">Second</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ek9Ch/

Comment: try ```$(".container").children(".red").first()```

Comment: There is a css tag in the question so i'm assuming he aims for a css only solution.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to do it with CSS. Not jQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-classnth-of-, there is also a quite detailed answer, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/3269863

Comment: Damn, feeling like a css ninja as my approach was quiet similar lol. Thanks for like @Marguez :)

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: From [this aswer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287975/1763929) -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8PB/73/)

Comment: @Vucko strange how it's almost exactly the same question, with similar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
.container .red:nth-child(2)
{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Works for this situation. But if I have a lot of p elements without class before first "red"?

Comment: Let's me explain why this answer won: it did what I need - select required element using ONE css expression

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not very pretty but does the job:

```
.container p + p.red {
    color: red;
}

.container p + p.red ~ p {
    color:black; /*reverting back*/
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/ek9Ch/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.container p[class=red]:nth-child(2)
        {
            color: red;
        }
```